# Visual studio development environment using linux server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, samba

I know the question is out of scope but asking to get a better advice.

Requirement: Need to build a small visual studio development environment for windows/web programming without windows server since the windows server licenses are above my budget.
My plan: 
Create a CentOS Samba PDC with apache, subversion and OracleXE installed and each windows client user should login to the linux PDC for authentication. The users will get the permissions inherited for windows as well as for visual studio. 
My Problem:
Windows Xp clients can be added to the linux pdc and the user can login as a regular windows user. 
How to configure samba to provide inherited security permissions for windows clients for a development environment?
Windows XP clients supports login to linux, but Windows 7 and Vista client won't, how to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Update samba to the latest version. Windows Vista & 7 have some new functionality and breaking changes, which of course were not yet implemented in the old/older samba version/s.